# Book with blob-like non-humanoid alien that fuses with human

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Looking for a book I read a long time ago. These are the few things I remember from it, sadly can't remember the plot or any names.

The aliens in the book are non-humanoid, like blobs. The alien species can create things with their minds. They may have been responsible for creating galaxies, including ours.

There's a scene where two of them create their offspring by willing it into being simultaneously. There's an alien who is involved in some kind of plot that he has to hide by imposing a timed selective amnesia on himself so that while he is in the presence of their leader he has no knowledge of the plot.

One young alien escapes or runs away from his home universe and collides with a human space ship either in an attack or accident. The alien and one human survive but both are too damaged to survive long. The alien convinces the human to merge bodies so that they will both survive. The human returns to earth and he appears normal but slightly bigger(and healthier?) because of the alien's added mass/influence. They share some kind of parasitic/symbiotic/voyeuristic mental relationship but I can't remember the details.

Comment: Parts of this sound vaguely like Hal Clement's [*Needle.*](http://www.amazon.com/Needle-Hal-Clement/dp/B0017GXBXY/ref=tmm_mmp_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&sr=&qid=)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before in here, but apparently I can't find the right words to search for.

Comment: The alien and it's effect on humans sounds like the "Old Galactics" from James Schmitz's stories about the Hub.

Comment: I have also been trying to remember what this book is called for a few years. I think there are 2 bounty hunters of the same race as the one who crashed, trying to find it.

Answer (score 5):

Man Of Two Worlds by Frank and Brian Herbert

*Edit to expand on this answer*

I too was trying to remember this book for years. After reading this post i carried on using google, remembering a few extra points, like how the eyes swivelled inwards, when they are creating things with their minds.  Google lead me to the possibility it could be Man Of Two Worlds, and it kind of fitted, since i remember reading it around the time i first read the Dune series. So I bought it, and it is the book we both remembered :)

Points you remembered . . .

> The aliens in the book are non-humanoid, like blobs.

Blobs with 4 legs, 2 arms and "floppy" ears

> The alien species can create things with their minds

By "rotating their eyes inwards" they can create living and non-living matter

> They may have been responsible for creating galaxies, including ours.

One of them created our galaxy and is referenced to, but not in the book directly.

> There's a scene where two of them create their offspring by willing it into being simultaneously.

Kind of. They use a "seed" and use their minds to help grow it, and pass on traits they wish their offspring to have.

> There's an alien who is involved in some kind of plot that he has to hide by imposing a timed selective amnesia on himself so that while he is in the presence of their leader he has no knowledge of the plot.

Yup. He somehow breaks the neurons so he has no knowledge of the stuff he wishes hidden. In a way how they will regenerate. They kind of do a "council" thing, where they can read each others thoughts, and this is his way of hiding stuff from the leader.

> One young alien escapes or runs away from his home universe and collides with a human space ship either in an attack or accident.

Kind of runs away, as he is wanting adventure. And crashes with the human ship.

> The alien and one human survive but both are too damaged to survive long. The alien convinces the human to merge bodies so that they will both survive.

Kind of. No convincing required. The human is in no state to object. The alien merges with him to survive.

> The human returns to earth and he appears normal but slightly bigger(and healthier?) because of the alien's added mass/influence.

Taller (extra mass) and stronger. Also no longer needs glasses

> They share some kind of parasitic/symbiotic/voyeuristic mental relationship but I can't remember the details.

They talk to each other in the shared mind.

So pretty certain it is the book you were also looking for :)

thanks
MrMikeJJ

Answer (score 0):

This seems like [The Man of Two Worlds](https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tTP1TcwNcuoNDFg9BLMTcxTyE9TKCnPVyjPL8pJKQYAhI4JgQ&q=man+of+two+worlds&oq=Man+of+Two+Worlds&aqs=chrome.1.0i355j46l2j0j46j0i22i30l5.6425j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

- Published on - [1986](https://www.google.com/search?q=man+of+two+worlds+publishing+date&oq=man+of+two+worlds+publishing+date&aqs=chrome..69i57.6287j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- Written by - [Brian and Frank Herbert](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02wZIhViE4rciO56enfmbZy-LW_wg%3A1614311909642&ei=5XE4YIXsJpjWz7sP5MGp8Aw&q=man+of+two+worlds+authors&oq=man+of+two+worlds+authors&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgcIABBHELADOgYIABAWEB46CAghEBYQHRAeUN36BFibggVgrIMFaAJwAngAgAGEAogB6QuSAQUwLjEuNpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjF8ri_1IbvAhUY63MBHeRgCs4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5)

From what I found on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Two_Worlds_(novel)):-

"One young alien escapes or runs away from his home universe and collides with a human space ship either in an attack or accident. The alien and one human survive but both are too damaged to survive long. The alien convinces the human to merge bodies so that they will both survive. The human returns to earth and he appears normal but slightly bigger(and healthier?) because of the alien's added mass/influence. They share some kind of parasitic/symbiotic/voyeuristic mental relationship but I can't remember the details."

> a youngster, Ryll, embarks on an unauthorized jaunt across space. Forced for survival to merge bodies with an “Earther” whose mind is as strong as his own, he has to battle for control

"The aliens in the book are non-humanoid, like blobs. The alien species can create things with their minds. They may have been responsible for creating galaxies, including ours."

> All of the Universe is the creation of the Dreens, who possess the power of "imaging", turning their thoughts into reality. They can create whole worlds, of which the wild, ungovernable planet Earth is one.

Also : By "rotating their eyes inwards" they can create living and non-living matter. (credit - MrMikeJJ)